# Right mouse click on context menu

Tags: wpf, triggers, contextmenu

When I right click on a `ContextMenu` in WPF it vanishes.  How can I prevent this behavior?

I would like that a right click on an open `ContextMenu` will do something else.
(like open additional context menu above it)

something like this:

```
<TextBlock.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu.Items>
                    <MenuItem Header="World"/>
                </ContextMenu.Items>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ContextMenu.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu.Items>
            <MenuItem Header="Hellow"/>
        </ContextMenu.Items>
    </ContextMenu>
</TextBlock.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible because `ContextMenu` captures the mouse, the popup closes because the control is automatically wired to close the popup when the mouse loses capture (In your case by right-clicking on the menu Item).

You can use [PopUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) instead to achive your problem.